# My react form is not submitting correctly

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios, submit

i have a problem with my react's form.

If I click **twice** on the submit button then at this moment, the form submits correctly and sends my various information to the database.

Where is the problem ?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Register = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setUsername(document.querySelector(".usernameInput").value);
    setPassword(document.querySelector(".passwordInput").value);
    const user = {
      username: username,
      password: password
    }
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/add', user)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data));

    console.log("lancement du formulaire");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>TEST Form</h1>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Username</label>
          <input required type="text" className="usernameInput" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input required type="password" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
      <input type="submit" value="Create User" className="btn btn-primary" className="passwordInput" />           </div>
       </form>
    </div>
  )
}
  
 export default Register;
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useState` is asynchronous just like `setState` in class components. You can't update the state on one line and assume it's already changed on the next one. You'll likely use the unchanged state.

When you create the `user` object, the state is not yet updated.

You need to click twice on the submit button because:

- on the first click you set the `username` and `password` states' value to the input value but as the state is not updated, you send the `user` objects with empty properties
- on the second click (when the state is updated) you can send the `user` object, as the `user` object contains the state values

The following should work (though I would recommend not to use it):

```js
const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const user = {
    username: document.querySelector('.usernameInput').value,
    password: document.querySelector('.passwordInput').value,
  };
  
  axios
    .post('http://localhost:5000/users/add', user)
    .then((res) => console.log(res.data));

  console.log('lancement du formulaire');
};
```

But why do you use states `username` and `password` if you never use them? If you've already added the states to store the input values, you can update them on changes and submit them on form submit:

```
const Register = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      username,
      password,
    };

    axios
      .post('http://localhost:5000/users/add', user)
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data));

    console.log('lancement du formulaire');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>TEST Form</h1>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Username</label>
          <input
            required
            type="text"
            className="usernameInput"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            required
            type="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Create User"
            className="btn btn-primary"
            className="passwordInput"
          />{' '}
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```